# Most compatible Java on Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, java

I have run my `.jar` code on Raspberry Pi 3B - Raspbian Buster with Oracle Java 8 (`1.8.0_241`). The code will completely run after ~80 seconds.

It's read that some java versions/models (like openJdk, etc) have different performances. For this, please check [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=25418) out. The problem with this link is that it's for approximately 7 years ago and benchmarks are not helpful with Raspbian Buster and Java 8.

All I need is to be sure that I can't reduce this runtime if I install another java version/model OR something else.

Thanks in advance.